# SimpleHTTPServer adding multiple handlers

Tags: python

I am not a Python programmer, but the I have used SimpleHTTPServer as it is so simple to start a web server serving from one folder.

Now I need to serve a json file. I have the following python:

update: I should mention that the file should be served from a different route. That is that I need both the "localhost" folder serving an index.html and a folder serving the json file.

```
import BaseHTTPServer, SimpleHTTPServer
import ssl

httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(('localhost', 4443), SimpleHTTPServer.update: I should mention that the )
httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket (httpd.socket, certfile='Certificates.pem', server_side=True)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

I know that I need to add one more handler serving the file, but how can you have multiple handlers.

The requirement for serving the file is:
1. It must be sent with the header ‘application/pkcs7-mime’
2. It must return a 200 http code

The question is how to server multiple handlers. Thanks in advance.
Regards

Comment: I recommend using Flask, it's probably easier to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need multiple handlers. `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` uses the the file's extension to guess an appropriate mime type for the `Content-type` header.

In this case extension `.p7m` maps to `application/pkcs7-mime`

So if you name your json files with extension `.p7m`, the desired mime type will be used.

If that is not feasible, then you can modify `SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.extensions_map` and add your own extension to map to `application/pkcs7-mime`:

```
import BaseHTTPServer, SimpleHTTPServer
import ssl

SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.extensions_map['.my_ext'] = 'application/pkcs7-mime'
httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(('localhost', 4443), SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket (httpd.socket, certfile='Certificates.pem', server_side=True)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Now files with extension `.my_ext` will be served with the required mime type.

If that doesn't work for you, then you can subclass `SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` and override its `guess_type()` method to add some custom way to determine the mime type, possibly by inspecting the file contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your operating system’s symlink (symbolic link) feature to link both the `index.html` and the JSON file into one directory.

On a Unix system, it goes like this:

```
$ ln -s /path/to/index.html

$ ln -s /another/path/to/file.json

$ ls
file.json  index.html

$ python /your/script.py
```